# How can I serialize a PHP DateTime to a JavaScript DateTime?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, datetime

I am using the [Symfony Serializer Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) to serialize some PHP objects to JSON. Among them are DateTime objects.

The JSON output I get for a PHP DateTime object is as follows:

```
{
    "lastErrors" : {
        "warning_count" : 0,
        "warnings" : [],
        "error_count" : 0,
        "errors" : []
    },
    "timezone" : {
        "name" : "UTC",
        "location" : {
            "country_code" : "??",
            "latitude" : 0,
            "longitude" : 0,
            "comments" : ""
        }
    },
    "offset" : 0,
    "timestamp" : 1416903372
}
```

To actually work with this object I need to convert the timestamp to a JS DateTime object. Also this will probably fail on some machines when the 32-bit timestap overflows in a few years.

How can I make the Symfony Serializer output PHP DateTime objects as JavaScript DateTime objects?

Comment: It seems the "timestamp" is seconds since UNIX epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00z). Javascript uses the same epoch but a [*time value*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1) in milliseconds, so use `new Date(date.timestamp * 1e3)`. You haven't indicated the sign of the offset or the units, so convert to milliseconds and add or subtract it as appropriate to make the time value UTC.

Comment: like @RobG said, this also looks like a pure json object if u put { and } arround it - but i dont use symfony2, so please ignore it if symfony2 works with json ;)

Comment: @RobG I am aware that I could convert this to a JS timestamp. However, I have quite a few of these objects in different places in the code and I need to compare them. I would prefer to avoid sending all the overhead data and then converting them all on the client side.

Comment: @UnskilledFreak The code snippet I posted is actually part of a larger JSON object, I just forgot to add back the enclosing braces. I fixed it now.